# ¿Cómo puedo encontrar la ruta de un proyecto de un servidor?

Tags: c#, aplicación-web, visual-studio-2017

Me pidieron revisar una parte del login que manda mensajes erróneos. Pero actualmente no tengo credenciales para iniciar el Login. Solo me dijeron la dirección del servidor.

La dirección del menú es **http://localhost/portal** pero en la parte que necesito entrar tiene la dirección **http://localhost:86/** y no encuentro la ubicación del proyecto para corregirlo. Alguien sabe de alguna forma de encontrarlo?

Ya encontré el archivo que principal (Portal) porque en el head tenia escrito el nombre del archivo, pero el archivo que muestra en el login no lo encuentro, me parece que el proyecto esta desarrollado en C#

[image: Ésta es la dirección del login que quiero encontrar]
[image: El Login que muestra es este]

Comment: Algo que puedas mostrar?

Comment: si es iis proba https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/webadministration/get-webapplication?view=windowsserver2022-ps ; https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/jj635844(v=ws.11) ... https://www.google.com/search?q=iis+find+all+apps+running+paths

Comment: Pues si es c# no tiene porque estar el código fuente

Comment: si Es una maquina de desarrollo, habré el visual estudio

Comment: Solo me dijeron la dirección del servidor: localhost es tu maquina local